# Vue.js - When clicking on a link on one page, links are being fired on page thats loading

Tags: cordova, vue.js

I am working on a PhoneGap/Cordova project with Vue.js. I have two pages: Page 1 contains a list of items and Page 2 is the detailed version of the item. Page 2 contains various links also.

[Example of Pages - Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGfSB.png)

I have reports that in some instances when a user taps on various positions in the list item (on page 1), that tap would execute a tap on the target page (page 2).

So, in the [Mockup Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGfSB.png), a user taps on position T1, the page would flicker really quick to page 2, then go to Link 1. Same for T2 going to Link 2 and T3 going to Link 3.

Any ideas what is going on? How do I mitigate this issue?

Comment: Show your research along along with your [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova on iOS (WebView) has a 300ms delay in registering touch events. Click and touch are technically two different types of events. What seems to be going on is the frontend registers the 'click' event, the pages loads then a touch event fires 300ms later, thereby clicking on the second page.

I ended up adding a 500ms delay in the router guard beforeEach. Maybe there is another elegant way of doing this but for now, this seems to work.